# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/...: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception, fileinputstream

hello I'm trying to upload a file to my application and on some devices for uploading from sdcard it gives me an error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: (path in sdcard): open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory). anybody have any idea why?? My code:

browsing file and opening file manager:

```
 private void doBrowseFile()  {
    Intent chooseFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    chooseFileIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    // Only return URIs that can be opened with ContentResolver
    chooseFileIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    chooseFileIntent = Intent.createChooser(chooseFileIntent, "Choose a file");
    startActivityForResult(chooseFileIntent, UNIQUE_REQUEST_CODE);
} 

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == UNIQUE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri fileUri = data.getData();
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Uri: " + fileUri);

                String filePath = null;
                try {
                    filePath = FileUtils.getPath(this, fileUri);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error: " + e);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                getBase64FromPath(filePath);
            }
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Encoding file from file path:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public void getBase64FromPath(String path) {
    String base64 = "";
    try {
        File file = new File(path);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length() + 100];
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file); //THIS LINE GIVES ME ERROR
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        int length = fileInputStream.read(buffer);
        base64 = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, 0, length,
                Base64.DEFAULT);
        uploadFile(base64);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "error:" + e.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

If anybody know any idea why please tell. It gives this error on some devices only. on the others it works perfectly fine. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `FileUtils.getPath()`, as it will never work reliably.

You can get an `InputStream` on your content by calling `getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri)`. You can then use that `InputStream` instead of the `FileInputStream` to read in your content.

Note that your app will crash with an `OutOfMemoryError` with large PDFs. I **strongly** recommend that you find some way to upload your content without reading it all into memory at once. For example, you might consider not converting it to base-64.

Comment: didn't work. it gave me nullpointer exception. Also about pdf, I'm giving base64 to php and decode it there and save it in a folder and whenever I needed just encode it and send it to my app and decode it the. is there any way better??

Comment: @AZIN: "is there any way better?" -- people have been uploading binary content to Web services for 20+ years *without* base64.

Comment: thank you. can you give me a link so I can read more about it? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: @AZIN: Sorry, but I have very little experience with PHP. It's possible that PHP itself has some limitations here that force you to use base64. I am used to other server-side options (e.g., Ruby/Rack, Kotlin/http4k), where you can just have the Web service support ordinary file uploads, `PUT` requests, etc.